# How to prevent Stateful Widget stored in List to be disposed?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget, statefulwidget

Let me start by explaining the problem. I have several buttons which are created based on data I'm getting from a server. On each button click I need to create and display a widget which will present me some data (this widget is also built dynamically). The state of this widget has to be preserved during the lifetime of the app. (for example if I click another button and show a different widget, I need to be able to click on the first button and show the first widget in its preserved state). Number of buttons can also be changed during the app lifetime.

I tried using IndexedStack to achieve this, but when the number of buttons is changed I need to add "pages" to IndexedStack, therefore I need to recreate a new IndexedStack which will have some of my old widgets, so I pull widgets from a List or create new ones if needed. This works great, except Flutter calls dispose() method on my widgets which are stored in the list. I tried using the AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixIn but it didn't help.

I'm guessing this has something to do that the widgets get detached from the parent, but when I reattach them to new parent (new Indexed stack) Flutter doesn't figure out this properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you found the solution? I am stuck on the same problem, how to prevent dispose method

Answer (score 0):

Try to store data to local storage or sqlite for persistence data.